# Nginx return 404 when executing script

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, fpm

I have the php script in en /var/www/myproyect/public/scripts/myscript.php

I'm using php 7.4 with nginx and php-fpm

The file exists, if I open a txt it opens it without problem,
but when it is a .php they return 404

```
location  ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
 }
```

Response of curl -I https://myurl/scripts/myscript.php:

HTTP/2 404
server: nginx/1.14.2
date: Tue, 14 Dec 2021 12:18:44 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 169

Comment: Where is your `root` statement?

Comment: root /var/www/myproyect/public; is this

Comment: Is it in the `server` block? Or another `location` block? The `location` block in your question needs to inherit a valid value for `root`.

Comment: In my server block: root /var/www/myproyect/public; but my script is in /var/www/myproyect/public/scripts/

Comment: In order to diagnose this problem further, you need to look at the entire configuration (use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files. Use `curl -I https://example.com/scripts/myscript.php` to understand the server's response together with the access and error logs.

Comment: Also, you could try commenting out the `try_files` statement and then checking the error log, because that is masking any read errors.

Comment: I have updated the question with the information you requested, thank you very much

Comment: You have so many `server` blocks, it's difficult to understand which one is handling the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to specify the folder where the script is located, with this configuration it works correctly

```
location ~ /scripts/myscript.php {
   try_files $uri $is_args$args;
   error_page 405 =200 $uri;
   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.\.php)(/.)$;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   include fastcgi_params;
}
```

---

*Answered by OP in question, removed and added as answser*